# match routes names in angular for custom title

Tags: angular

I have different path in my app, and would like to display a title in the tab for each route.

I currently made some variables that looks like this :

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = {
  pages: {
    public: {
      path: '',
      link: '/',
      children: {
        signIn: {
          path: 'sign-in',
          link: '/sign-in',
        },
        passwordChangeConfirmation: {
          path: 'password-change/:token',
          link: '/password-change',
        },
      },
    },
 }
}
```

and another with the name and icon

```
export const ROUTE_DISPLAY = {
  [ROUTES.pages.public.children.signIn.link]: {
    title: 'PUBLIC.SIGN_IN.TITLE',
    icon: 'assets/svg/report-light.svg',
  },
  [ROUTES.pages.public.children.passwordChangeConfirmation.link]: {
    title: 'PUBLIC.CHANGE_PASSWORD.TITLE',
    icon: 'assets/svg/report-light.svg',
  },
```

Then I get the name like this in a function

```
return ROUTE_DISPLAY[router?.state?.url]
```

It works good but if there is parameter (like `:token`) in the url it won't work.

Do I have to make a manual function that remove eventual parameters etc.. or is there some router method that allow to assign title to routes ?

Answer (score 0):

This is where   https://angular.io/api/router/Route#route is used for. you could add title variable to each route like this

```
    var routes = [ 
       {
          path:"users",
          component:"Users component",
          data:{
             title:"users"
          }
       }  
   ]
```

and then use   `router?.data?.title` property instead of `router?.state?.url`